# Integration of Web based application (from client) to POS Terminal

Tags: interface, integration

**Scenario :**

- A J2ee based ERP application hosted in Amazon EC2 cloud
- Clients use web browsers (Firefox/Chrome) to access application

**Requirement :**

- Need to integrate POS terminal with client browser, read few card information and auto populate the payment related fields while billing

**Question :**

- Is it Feasible in anyway (JS?, Applet?, Plugins?) to integrate to POS terminal with a browser
- If Yes, Can I get some pointers to start the research?

I have googled and could not find any thing related to my problem.
Device is POS Machine - Verifone VX520

Thanks

Comment: One way is to communicate with a serial port to the Vx520 and send transaction commands such as SALE, PREAUTH, FORCE with the amounts from the computer. If you want the data from the card would it be easier to get it through a generic card reader (mag stripe data only), sort the data out and populate your fields?

Comment: @Baz Point is that, mine s a webapplication and it is operated within the web browser. So how can I connect to serial port from web browsers? Webbrowsers are not allowed to access local resources.

Comment: did you solve the problem? If yes can you answer to the question?